# How to get value from firebase database show in p element

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to create chat app using firebase database. 
I have html:

```
<input type="text" name="txt" id="txt">
<button type="submit" id="btn-send" onclick="addElement()">SEND</button>
<p id="list-message"></p>
```

and javascript :

```
var rootRef = firebase.database();
var message = rootRef.ref().child('/message');

function addElement() {
    var x = document.getElementById('txt').value;
    var node = document.createElement("li");
    var text = document.createTextNode(x);

    node.appendChild(text);
    document.getElementById('list-message').appendChild(node);
    message.push().set({
        Message: $("#txt").val()
    });
}
```

Screenshot of my Firebase data

[image: .]

How can I retrieve all the data and show as a list in `<p id="list-message"></p>`?

Comment: You need to listen for child_added events... https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a data listener which looks out for changes in the `message` node then update `<p id="list-message"></p>`.

```
message.on('child_added', function(snapshot) {
  var msg = snapshot.val();
  var msgDiv = document.createElement("div");
  msgDiv.textContent = msg.Message;
  document.getElementById("list-message").appendChild(msgDiv);
});
```

Refer to this codelab for more on how to build a chat app: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cloud-firebase-chat/.